# Reactjs: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pretty simple react project setup:

```
├── app.js
├── components
│   ├── MainWrapper.js
│   └── html.js
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

The application is started by:

```
node server.js
```

Which uses the express server and renders markup for an HtmlComponent in html.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainWrapper from './MainWrapper.js'

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <title>My Awesome Site</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="awesome.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="root"></div>
                </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
}

export default HtmlComponent;
```

The goal is to create a Wrapper that will fill the 'root' div.  It's very simple right now:

MainWrapper.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var MainWrapper = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button>go</button>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<MainWrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When I run node server.js there's an exception:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Simple/components/MainWrapper.js:36
_react2['default'].render(_react2['default'].createElement(MainWrapper, null), document.getElementById("root"));
                                                                               ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/Simple/components/MainWrapper.js:27:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/me/Desktop/Simple/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/me/Desktop/Simple/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/Simple/components/Html.js:5:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

I do not understand why document is not defined.  It seems it's simple javascript.

Comment: are you rendering this server-side?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60629258/12860895

Answer (score 72, accepted):

if you're rendering this server side, there will be no "document" object. try wrapping it in the following:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    React.render(<MainWrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

this will check to see if a window object is present - meaning its in the browser - which also means that the document object is present

---

**to keep this answer valid**

Newer versions of React have been split into multiple packages, you will need to import from `react-dom` now:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDOM.render(<MainWrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Abdul.  I wrapped React.render(...) like you suggested.  I still get the same error.

Comment: do you have a build process? did you re-build? did you restart the server? try all those steps

Comment: Ok.  I ran npm rebuild.  It took a few times for some reason.  I don't get the error...  Must be doing this server side somehow.  I will investigate.

Comment: cool glad I can help! I ran into this myself when I was learning react for the first time

Comment: Hi. I tried to wrap it in an if statement and it didn't seem to work for me. I'm using webpack and when I try to run the server it says "document is not defined"

Comment: Figured it out. I had not been using the string "undefined" and rather just undefined

Answer (score 3):

`document` won't be defined when rendering on the server - try wrapping the `React.render()` call in `if(typeof window !== 'undefined') { }`.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you add this code documentation block at the top of the your test file

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Comment: Worked great for my issues with Jest. - Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my unit tests with Jest.

```
/** @jest-environment jsdom */
```

This did the job for me