# ReferenceError: document is not defined (React SSR, Webpack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to do server-side rendering my react app but it doesn't work. It shows **document** not define when trying to run. This error only shows when I used **CSS** file in app.js file. Though client-side render working properly.

```js
//My App.js
import React from 'react';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import ErrorBoundary from './validation/ErrorBoundry';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/scss/main.css';

const App = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <ErrorBoundary>{renderRoutes(route.routes)}</ErrorBoundary>
    </div>

  );
};
export default App;


//webpack.base.js

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
          { 
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
            ],
          }
        ]
    },
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78qkr.png)

Comment: you not need to import css files in source code if your bundler is webpack. Read webpack or css vendor documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068451/reactjs-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

The document object is the root node of the HTML document.
This object does not exist in node application.
And the way to handle it in node application can be done by using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

> jsdom is a pure-JavaScript implementation of many web standards,
>   notably the WHATWG DOM and HTML Standards, for use with Node.js

That mistake happens because, **Webpack** transforms the CSS to the following code:

```
var css_main_css = document.createElement("style");
css_main_css.innerHTML = "*css*";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(css_main_css);
```

Comment: how do I use jsdom  for server-side rendering, can you give me a snippet code.