# Next.js: document is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a payment form where people can pay but I keep getting this error.

> document is not defined

I'm using Next.js. Please see my code below:

```
import React from "react";
import {Elements, StripeProvider} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CheckoutForm from '../../components/Payment/CheckoutForm';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';


var stripe_load = () => {
    var aScript = document.createElement('script');
    aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

    document.head.appendChild(aScript);
    aScript.onload = () => {

    };
};

function Payment({host}) {
    const key = host.includes('localhost') ? 'test' : 't';

    stripe_load();

    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div className="Payment Main">
            <StripeProvider apiKey={key}>
                <Elements>
                    <CheckoutForm planid={router.query.id}/>
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p>Powered by Stripe</p>
        </div>
    );
};


Payment.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    return { host: ctx.req.headers.host }
};

export default Payment
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35068451/12860895

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think, in server rendering mode, the document is undefined.
You should be able to use it inside class lifecycle methods or useEffect

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {Elements, StripeProvider} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CheckoutForm from '../../components/Payment/CheckoutForm';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';


var stripe_load = () => {
    var aScript = document.createElement('script');
    aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

    document.head.appendChild(aScript);
    aScript.onload = () => {

    };
};

function Payment({host}) {
    const key = host.includes('localhost') ? 'test' : 't';

    useEffect(() => {
      var aScript = document.createElement('script');
       aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
       aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

       document.head.appendChild(aScript);
       aScript.onload = () => {

       };
    }, [])
    //stripe_load();

    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div className="Payment Main">
            <StripeProvider apiKey={key}>
                <Elements>
                    <CheckoutForm planid={router.query.id}/>
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p>Powered by Stripe</p>
        </div>
    );
};


Payment.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    return { host: ctx.req.headers.host }
};

export default Payment
```

Comment: Using document INSIDE useEffect worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

For example, when the module includes a library that only works in the browser. Some times dynamic import can solve this issue.

Take a look at the following example:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Other useful references:

- [Stack Overflow - Getting errors when rendering a component with dynamic in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75370953/4756173)
- [Next.js Docs - With no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr)

Answer (score 29):

You need to wrap your `document` using validator `process.browser`, because this document is belong to client side, and the error occured when nextjs render in server side.

```
var stripe_load = () => {
    if (process.browser) {
        var aScript = document.createElement('script');
        aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

        document.head.appendChild(aScript);
        aScript.onload = () => {

        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Please note, `process.browser` has been decprecated. You should now use `typeof window === 'undefined'`.    Refer to https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5354#issuecomment-520305040

Comment: Anyone knows why this happen even if we put "use client"?

Answer (score 28):

for me, this error occurs from lots of mistakes:
first, you have to use

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
```

for every `window.` and `document.` and especially for `localStorage.` functions (my self forgot to use this if clause for localStorage.getItem and the error didn't fix)

another problem was the import of the line below which was totally **wrong**!:

```
import {router} from "next/client";
```

Comment: I believe this is the most correct and up-to-date answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

To access the document in Next.js you need await the page render first then get it in a variable, like so:

```
const [_document, set_document] = React.useState(null)

React.useEffect(() => {
    set_document(document)
}, [])
```

Comment: But that's scoped to a component? This is not document, but a piece of state in the component that this useState hook is declared.

Answer (score 7):

You should read the difference between JS in node.js and JS in Browser. In node.js, you don't have DOM APIs (window, document, document.getElementById,...), the thing can be only have when your HTML is rendered in a thing called windows of Browsers. So next.js use node.js to run JS code and take result to render HTML file. But in node.js, nothing is windows of Browser.

My English is quite bad. But I hope this answer will be helpful for you.

Comment: can you please give a reference that elaborates on these differences?  I am running into a lot of the same issues.  I thought I was building a node.js app and I'm getting errors that indicate I'm running JS within an index.html.  I need to reframe my understanding of the two models, how they are situated within the web, etc.  I also realize they can (and typically do) work together.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a new feature called [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) with ssr off. this is a workaround for rerendering the component.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error while using bootstrap-5 in nextjs project .

[image]

It will be reolved by requiring script in **useEffect()** hook in **_app.js**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import '@/styles/globals.css'

config.autoAddCss = false;

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**this solution is loosely related**
I dont know why I thought you were using Tailwind Elements when I wrote this...

Here is my working solution on Next.js 13.4.10 using AppRouter:
To use the component without errors, **you must dynamically import with no server-side rendering.**
see this page.tsx:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ButtonDy = dynamic(() => import("./mycomponents/Button"), {ssr: false});

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ButtonDy>Epic Button</ButtonDy>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here is the 'Button.tsx' component:

```tsx
'use client'

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { initTE, Ripple } from "tw-elements";

const Button: React.FC<{
  children?: React.ReactNode,
}> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    initTE({ Ripple });
  }, []);
  return(<>
    <button
      type="button"
      data-te-ripple-init
      data-te-ripple-color="light"
      className="inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)] dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]">
      {children}
    </button>
  </>);
}

export default Button;
```

another example on Tailwind Elements Docshttps://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/integrations/next-integration/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have two things setup.

1. DOM render is completed.
2. Then load the function.

Step 1: create hook isMounted this will make sure that your DOM is rendered.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function RenderCompleted() {

    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMounted(true)

        return () => {
            setMounted(false)
        }
    });

    return mounted;
}

export default RenderCompleted;
```

Inside function Payment load the hook :

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {Elements, StripeProvider} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CheckoutForm from '../../components/Payment/CheckoutForm';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import RenderCompleted from '../hooks/isMounted';

var stripe_load = () => {
    var aScript = document.createElement('script');
    aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

    document.head.appendChild(aScript);
    aScript.onload = () => {

    };
};

function Payment({host}) {
    const[key,setKey] = useEffect('');

    //will help you on re-render or host changes

    useEffect(()=>{
        const key = host.includes('localhost') ? 'test' : 't';
        setKey(key);
    },[host])


    useEffect(() => {
      var aScript = document.createElement('script');
       aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
       aScript.src = " https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

       document.head.appendChild(aScript);
       aScript.onload = () => {

       };
    }, [isMounted])


    const router = useRouter();
    const isMounted = RenderCompleted();

    return (
        <div className="Payment Main">
            <StripeProvider apiKey={key}>
                <Elements>
                    <CheckoutForm planid={router.query.id}/>
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p>Powered by Stripe</p>
        </div>
    );
};


Payment.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    return { host: ctx.req.headers.host }
};

export default Payment
```

Another way to do this is, to use head component of next.js: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

```
<Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick solution, you can just separate your entire page into a different file, then import the entire page to your route file using dynamic import.

Answer (score -4):

This might be helpful to some else, I got this error when Material UI anchorEl is true

```
const [anchoeEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

<Menu 
    anchorEl={anchorEl}  
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top"
        horizontal: "right"
    }}
/>
```