# TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My `http://localhost:3000/renewal` has the following code

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Renewal() {

  return (
    <header>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          Go to home page
        </a>
      </Link>
    </header
  )
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite legacy code in my `_app.tsx` that has the following general structure

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, apollo }) => {
  const [isRenewalPage, setIsRenewalPage] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const header = document.querySelector('header')
    header.className = ''
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const pathname = window.location.pathname
      setIsRenewalPage(pathname.indexOf('renewal') > -1)
    }
  }, [Component])

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
      {isRenewalPage ? (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      ) :
        <div>
          <header>
            global header
          </header>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      }
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

The idea is that if I go to `http://localhost:3000/renewal`, I should get a clean `_app.tsx` and see my component `header`. If I go to any other page, then I will have the legacy code and see my global `header`.

The problem occurs when I try to go to my `http://localhost:3000/` from `http://localhost:3000/renewal`. I get the following error

[image: error]

I thought the error may be happening because the window did not fully load before the `useEffect` ran so I tried the following

```
     useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          const header = document.querySelector('header')
          header.className = ''
          const pathname = window.location.pathname
          setIsRenewalPage(pathname.indexOf('renewal') > -1)
        }
      }, [Component])
```

But the same error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629258/next-js-document-is-not-defined
no document on ssr on above your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the document object from within your useEffect(), even when server-side rendering. I think the problem here is that when React calls your component function, the useEffect hook is going to run regardless of whether or not isRenewalPage is true or false. *However*, you conditionally render the header element based on that value, so when isRenewalPage is true, document.querySelector('header') returns undefined because you haven't rendered any header elements (you've only rendered your Component). You can't access the 'className' property of undefined, so your app throws a TypeError.

Try

```
useEffect(() => {
    const header = document.querySelector('header')
    if (header) {
      header.className = ''
    }
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const pathname = window.location.pathname
      setIsRenewalPage(pathname.indexOf('renewal') > -1)
    }
  })
```