# NextJS ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: cookies, next.js

I am making a NextJS app. I am using cookies to save access tokens returned from REST API.
In `login.js`, cookies are being created successfully:

```
  document.cookie = `token=${res.data.result.accessToken}; path=/;`;
```

but when I access it in `header.js` :

```
if (document.cookie.split(';').some((item) => item.trim().startsWith('token='))) {
     SetAuth("true");
}
```

it says;

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Any reason, or any other way to save tokens and access them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629258/next-js-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as Nextjs use SSR you don't access to document when code is being executed in server side running phase, you can do some checks to know if your code is being executed in browser, you can check solutions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629258/next-js-document-is-not-defined).

as a fast answer you can check if you have access to window object first

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
 // your code with access to window or document object here 
 }
```

Comment: I used this solution, but it didn't work. do you know any other way to come up with this problem ?