# How can I disable scrolling when there's a modal using nextjs tailwind?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I currently have this code set up but I don't think this is the correct one to use as it gives me "document is not defined".

```
export default function Modal() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

//   BELOW IS THE ERROR

  if (modal) {
    document.body.classList.add('active-modal');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active-modal');
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629258/next-js-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test the result but try to write the if statement inside `useEffect()` hook. I think initially the document object is unknown to nextJs same goes for the global window object!

For side-effects always try to use `useEffect()` hook. `useEffect()` runs after the component is mounted on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs you can disable scrolling by doing something like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden"
```

and

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = ""
```

to restore the scrolling.