# Getting errors when rendering a component with dynamic in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-leaflet

I am trying to render `Leaflet` maps in Next.js using Typescript. I read that ssr needed to be disabled to avoid the 'window not defined' problem, but when trying this to generate the map:

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

export const Leaflet: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={{ lat: 48.71291, lng: 44.52693 }} zoom={13}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright%22%3EOpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

and this to render it:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../components/Leaflet"), {
    ssr: false,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <MapWithNoSSR/>
    </>
    );
  };

export default Home
```

TypesSript gives me this error:

> Argument of type '() => Promise<typeof
> import("/src/components/Leaflet")>' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.   Type '() => Promise<typeof
> import("/src/components/Leaflet")>' is not assignable to type '() =>
> LoaderComponent<{}>'.

And the browser gives this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to:
> [object Module]. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or
> function.

Has anyone here experienced something similar and have some advice regarding how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting those errors because your `Leaflet` component is a named module, and you are trying to access it as if it was a default one. Change your code to as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-named-exports) says:

```typescript
import { NextPage } from "next";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// ⚠️: .then() is needed because the component is not exported with the default keyword
const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import("../components/Leaflet").then((module) => module.Leaflet),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MapWithNoSSR />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Also, notice I pushed the dynamic import outside of `Home`.