# ReferenceError: document is not defined (React)

Tags: javascript, dom, material-ui, react-router

I tried to render my main page working with routes and I still have the same ReferenceError.

Here's my code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "../components/app";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import {
 createBrowserRouter,
 RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Product from "./products/product";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
  path: "/",
  element: <App />,
},
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: What tool is giving you that error? Are you trying to run that code with Node.js? Is your IDE presenting you with the error without you trying to run it? Something else?

Comment: Does your HTML actually have a `root` element? Do you have some HTML to show?

Comment: I'm working with VS Code (npm environment) and I'm trying to render it in a browser passing throught my npm run dev command

Comment: So your browser is giving you this error?

Comment: @Marc, Working with JS files only, no root id declared on any tag

Comment: @Keith, yes exactly

Comment: mmm, that's odd.  `document` is a global it's not something that's usually undefined.  In your browser if you open the console and type `document` what does it say?

Comment: I wonder if your doing SSR, (Server Side Rendering). -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068451/reactjs-document-is-not-defined

Comment: @Keith it displays html tags

Comment: In the window were you type `npm run dev` do you see any messages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254425/discussion-between-salimkazi-and-keith).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068451/reactjs-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen as people are still replying to this question, during a Chat session with OP, it turns out he's using Next.JS, this does SSR and as such doesn't have `document` as it's using Server Side Rendering.

The solution for the OP, was just don't do any React mounting stuff in the first place, as this is all handled for you, including routing logic, Typescript support etc etc.

For those just starting React & using Next.JS, one bit of advice is to follow Next.JS specific documentation to start, and then move onto other React tutorials found on the internet, and then these will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`createRoot(rootElement)` is a React utility function used to create a react root element, which is a DOM element in which UI components render themselves. It takes as a parameter the root element that should be created. This root element is not a React component, it is simply an empty div element that is used for React to render itself.

So you should have an HTML file with empty div and `id="root"` in order to render the react page.