# NextJs 14 "ReferenceError: document not defined" and "prerendering error" how do you know which page the error is on?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, build

I get this error when I try to build (run build) my nextjs application. But I have a lot of files/pages and this error message doesn't say much to me. How do I find the exact location where this error is occurring. And what is the cause of this error?

```
Generating static pages (38/47) [==  ] 
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at e.exports (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/3871.js:1:68626)
    at 95136 (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/3871.js:1:154901)
    at t (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 83151 (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/5895.js:9:283)
    at t (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at F (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
    at $ (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:90488)
    at rC (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:33840)
    at n$ (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59861)
    at nj (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64628)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at e.exports (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/3871.js:1:68626)
    at 95136 (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/3871.js:1:154901)
    at t (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 83151 (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/chunks/5895.js:9:283)
    at t (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/packages/application/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at F (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
    at $ (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:90488)
    at rC (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:33840)
    at n$ (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59861)
    at nj (/Users/cardoso/workspace/qf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64628)
```

There are more errors like this, the message is very long. But they are basically the same as these

Comment: This answer most likely answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35068861/1442743

TL;DR: The document object is not available when rendering server-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068451/reactjs-document-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

if you are on server component, you have no access to `window` object. (document is property on window, window.document`. if you are on client component, since the client component is first rendered on the server, you have to set a guard before reaching` document`

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   console.log(window.document);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new nextjs project and adding each component, page, etc one by one. I discovered that this was a bug in "react-easy-print". I was using it in my UX components to set them as printable () or not (), just removing them made everything functional and buildable.
And the pre-render error had something to do with a wrong way of calling fetch and using hooks.