# using react-router-dom to add an additional page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, nestjs

Currently, I have a homepage (/) only. Now, I want to add an additional page with another path (/about) so I am trying to include the react router.

When I do this in the index.js, it works:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
  <HomePage></HomePage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

but when I do this:

```
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => {
  return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I get this error on localhost:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: document is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

I also tried this in the index.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  } else {
    // Handle server-side rendering (optional)
    return null;
  }
};
```

but then I would get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Home`.
```

What am I missing out on?

Comment: There's no `document` global in a Node context.

Comment: I am a beginner so I might need a little more help than that @Pointy

Comment: Have you tried `typeof window !== 'undefined'` as in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068451/reactjs-document-is-not-defined)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet seems to be attempting server-side rendering (SSR) of a React application using React Router. However, there are a few issues with this approach:

1. Server-side rendering usually involves different techniques and setups, including using libraries like Next.js for React applications.
2. React Router is typically not used directly for server-side rendering, as it's primarily a client-side routing library.
   Here's a simplified example of how you might handle server-side rendering with React using a different approach:

```js
// In your server-side rendering code (e.g., using Node.js and Express)
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App'; // Your main application component

// Express route handler for rendering React app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const appMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url);
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SSR React App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${appMarkup}</div>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
    `);
  }
});
```

> This code sets up server-side rendering using StaticRouter from react-router-dom to render the appropriate component based on the requested URL.

Comment: this looks like a AI generated response....