"Document is not" defined in React
I'm trying to create isomorphic react app. This is my current code:
server.js
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom/server';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import App from './components/App';
import routes from '../routes/routes.js';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB', err));

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('', routes);
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const appString = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  const html = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">${appString}</div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
  `;

  res.send(html);
});



app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running on port 3000'));

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = [
  {
    // Client bundle configuration
    entry: './src/client.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    devServer: {
      publicPath: '/',
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      compress: true,
      port: 9000,
      hot: true,
    },
  },
  {
    // Server bundle configuration
    entry: './src/server.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: 'server.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
  },
];

App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Archive from './Archive';

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> }  />
        <Route path="/archive" element={ <Archive /> }  />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </>
);

export default App;

client.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const root = document.getElementById('root');
  if (root) {
    ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />);
  }
}

After I run npm start I get Referrence Error: document is not defined. I think I understand the problem, but I cannot solve this.
I've got also problem with rendering. I feel like there is a problem with my server.js app.get problem.
I tried with checking every import/export and tried with
typeof window !=='undefined'
but nothing works.

Does this help with your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35068861/1832954

Nope, i tried this already. Still same error.
